# Do diamagnets, such as graphite, have a Curie point?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, atomic-physics, chemical-compounds

Since graphite can be heated by induction, can it also lose its magnetism at a certain temperature just like ferromagnetic metals? And what about materials such as graphene(that is also from carbon) or diamond? They do not seem to be magnetic or react under electromagnetic influence in any way shape or form, why is that?

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE. I do not have a reference right now but for the case of graphite, at large temperatures its magnetic susceptibility is almost a constant in temperature up to several thousands of kelvin (when it starts to melt). This generally the case for diamond.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Diamagnetism is an atomic orbital phenomenon not a collective one between electron spins of different atoms such as ferromagnetism. Thus unless the atoms ionize because of high temperature collisions diamagnetism stays.